# Gravity train and fastest path

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, lagrangian-formalism, planets, variational-calculus

As a fun exercise to kill some time, I have been thinking in the [gravity train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_train). For a point mass falling through a tunnel dug from pole to pole in an spherically symmetric planet of radius $R$, the time the objects takes to travel through it can be calculated, in Newtonian approximation:

$$\frac{\dot{r}}{r}-\frac{GM(r)}{r}=E\Rightarrow t=4\int_R^0\frac{dr}{\sqrt{2E+\frac{2GM(r)}{r}}},$$

being $M(r)$ the mass distribution of the planet. The initial conditions $r(0)=R, \dot{r}(0)=0$ lead to the factor $4$ in the time. Imposing this conditions and calling $M(R)=M_p$ (for mass of the planet), $E=-GM_pR^{-1}$.

I am trying to determine the functional form of $M(r)$ that minimize $t$, but I am not sure how to proceed.

In general this kind of problems should be treated with calculus of variations, but I am not sure how to proceed. Stating the problem in this way, we define the functional $t[r,\dot{r},M(r)]$, where the derivative is with respect to an internal parameter $\alpha$:

$$
t[r,\dot{r},M(r)]=4\int_{r(\alpha_i)}^{r_(\alpha_f)}\mathcal{L}[r,\dot{r},M(r)]d\!\alpha, \quad \mathcal{L}[r,\dot{r},M(r)]=\frac{\dot{r}}{\sqrt{2E+\frac{2GM(r)}{r}}}
$$

In my idea $M(r)$ should enter as a degree of freedom, since it is what we are trying to calculate; however given a mass function, the orbit $r(t)$ is determined by the equations of motion, so cannot be independent from $M(r)$. On the other hand there is still one constraint that I have not used:

$$
M(R)=M_p\mbox{ for }M(r)=4\pi\int_0^rx^2\rho(x)d\!x
$$

How can I describe the functional to acomodate $M(r)$ as a free parameter, in case it is possible?
How do I implement the constraint in the mass?

---

Edit: As pointed by @Qmechanic the intuitive solution would be all the mass concentrated into a point. To rule out that answer (or to make the problem more appealing to me), consider constraining the mass function in such way that at any given position $r$ the mass below should be less than the mass of a black hole with the same Schwarschild radius.

$$
M(r)=4\pi\int_0^r x^2\rho(x)dx<\frac{c^2r}{2G}.
$$

Then the solution could follow in an analogous way as the reasoning for a point-mass: maybe the solution that minimize the time is to concentrate the mass in spherical concentric shells such at each point the previous condition is satisfied, so the density profile $\rho(r)\sim r^{-2}$. How could I prove that this solution makes $t$ minimum (in case it actually does).

Comment: Intuitively, concentrating all mass at the center makes the fastest track.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks for the answer. I thought about it but I was thinking in something different. I try to edit the question to avoid such caveat.